# CASE or IF condition in WHERE clause for the below requirement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a below requirement but I do not know how to write a Oracle SQL query to fetch the data based on the given condition.

Requirement:

Person table

```
Name       created_date   updated_date
-------    -----------    ------------
Alex       11-oct-2018     
John       10-oct-2018    11-oct-2018
```

I want to fetch the records name, created_date or updated_date as last_modified_date based on from and to date that were given on UI and it should search on the updated_date like updated_date between fromdate and todate if updated_date is not null. if updated_date is null then it should search on created_date like created_date between fromdate and todate.

I tried like this, there are compilation issues, i do not how to write

```
select name,
       case when update_date is null then created_date else updated_date as last_modified_date 
from Person 
where case when updated_date is null 
           then trunc(created_date) between fromdate and todate 
           else trunc(updated_date) between fromdate and todate.'
```

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions in the WHERE clause, instead of case/coalesce etc.

Comment: can you provide sample output??

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: All answers listed here  worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

> CASE WHEN [condition] THEN [return_expr] ELSE [else_expr] END

```
Select name, 
       CASE WHEN update_date IS NULL
            THEN created_date
            ELSE updated_date END AS last_modified_date
  FROM Person
 WHERE CASE WHEN updated_date IS NULL
            THEN TRUNC(created_date)
            ELSE TRUNC(updated_date) END BETWEEN fromdate AND todate;
```

or using for oracle only:

> NVL([expr1], [expr2])

```
Select name, 
       NVL(update_date, created_date) AS last_modified_date
  FROM Person
 WHERE NVL(updated_date, created_date) BETWEEN fromdate AND todate;
```

Comment: I suggest using `COALESCE([EXPR1],[EXPR2],...[EXPRN])` instead of `NVL` as it's SQL92 standard, more powerful (it takes an arbitrary number of arguments) and not vendor-specific as NVL is

Comment: Both of the above queries worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. hari

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
select name, nvl(update_date,created_date) as last_modified_date
from Person 
where nvl(update_date,created_date) between fromdate and todate;
```

Answer (score 0):

your did mistake to write correct sql sytax on where clause, which will be like below

```
    select name, 
           case when update_date is null 
           then created_date else 
           updated_date end as last_modified_date 
    from Person
    where case when updated_date 
    is null then trunc(created_date)
      else 
    trunc(updated_date) end
    between fromdate and todate
```

BY using `COALESCE` function you can do same comparison

```
select name,COALESCE(update_date,created_date)
from Person
where COALESCE(update_date,created_date) between fromdate and todate
```

Your mistake area

```
    case when updated_date 
    is null then trunc(created_date) between fromdate and todate --here between is wrong sql syntax (condition)
   else 
    trunc(updated_date) between fromdate and todate --(same thing you did for else)
```

Comment: both of the above answers worked perfectly. Thanks Hari.